Is it a bad-practice to return sub-resources in a response for a parent-resource in REST?
Let's say I parent-resource groups/{group-id} with a sub-resource owners:

/groups/{group-id}
/groups/{group-id}/owners

Is it bad practice to include the owners sub-resource in a response for the /groups/{group-id} parent-resource in REST?
I have considered to include a query parameter for /groups/{group-id} called includeOwners, which would allow consumers to request the owners in the group response.
Should the consumer make two requests instead? I don't want to include query parameters for every single resource, as the number may growth.

For example, OData does this through its $expand parameter. I'd say it's OK to include children in the same result for the parent request, if the number of children is relatively low.

Thank you. But it should always be an option, like $expand or includeOwners? I should never include sub-resources in a parent-resource response by default?

depends on who's using it and how. if you're the user then your client application can dictate the API's interface (eg. have $expand for endpoints used in multiple places that need different segments of data from the response). if it's general purpose having options like $expand allows the possible users to query only the data they need. depending on the size of the sub-resource you can choose to either include it with the parent or have a separate endpoint for it.

TL;DR - There isn't going to be a right answer here, in that it's going to depend upon your use case.
I think its worth starting with the BFF (Backend for frontend) pattern - the basic idea is that if you have your application deployed in a datacenter you may not know in advance what the call sequence for a particular client looks like.
Instead you deploy an application in your datacenter (the BFF) that receives calls from the front end and makes calls (on the behalf of the client) to the appropriate backend services in order to service the request, the core advantages of this are that:

The client can make a single request.
The BFF has low latency (since its co-located with other services) hence it can make many requests.
The BFF can strip out any unnecessary data, so that the client only receives the data it needs.

The BFF pattern is designed for when you control both the client and the server (for example you have a mobile app that needs to talk to your backend servers).
The question is how close to this ideal situation can you get when you don't control the client?

Typically your data model will have a number of entities connected by different relationships:
1-to-1 and many-to-1
Consider including them in the result, in that it's quite likely the client is going to request them anyway, so you might as well send them. The exceptions would be if:

Very few clients need the other object.
The object is large - requiring significant bandwidth.
It's expensive to fetch/load the other object.

If you are not including the data by default, you have some options:

Force the client to make a separate request, if they want the data.
Include a flag/parameter in the request to indicate if the data should be added.
Have two different URL's where one includes the extra data and one doesn't.

Personally I am not a fan of having "optional" data, that is only included if certain flags are set - as I feel it makes the data model more difficult to understand, however you may be forced to use this approach.
1-to-many and many-to-many
These relationships have the potential to really blow up your data model, both in terms of data over the wire and time required to fetch the data from the database. As a result I would default to not including them in the result set.
That said a common use case is to display a list of things in a UI that the user may click on to drill down for more details. To satisfy this use case I typically create a "DisplayId" object which contains:

The primary key (int or GUID).
A display name - suitable for displaying in a list on the UI.

Then whenever there is a *-to-many relationship, I include a list of DisplayId's in my result.
many-to-many
Just a quick call out, that sometimes you hit a use case where you need fully populated objects on both sides of a many-to-many relationship.
In this case you may need to bite the bullet and have a dedicated endpoint that returns a list of pairs, where the objects in the pairs are the fully populated objects.

Sub-resources aren't a thing in REST; they are just resources.  In particular, REST/HTTP don't include any constraints that require two resources to be related just because the spellings of the identifiers for those resources happen to overlap.
What you are really asking is whether it is "OK" to include the representation of one resource within the representation of another resource.
And the answer is that it is "fine" to do that, so long as the trade offs are acceptable.
In the general case, you'll need to think about things like caching; if you have two different resources that change representations over time, then the cached copies can get out of sync.
Also, if the information of the "owners" resource changes more frequently than the group, then the group resource is going to have to adopt the freshness rules of the owners resource.
Similarly, if these are resources that we expect to edit on the client, there's no way to communicate to a general purpose component that modifying one should modify the other.

An example to consider from the web: when we want to render an image in a web page, we have two different options available: we can link to the image resource, or we can copy the image representation directly into the HTML (see RFC 2397).
Either way is "fine", in the sense that when you look in the browser, there's your picture.  But in one case, the picture changes when the browser fetches a fresh representation of the image resource, and in the other case the picture changes when the browser fetches a fresh representation of the html resource.
And depending on what you are doing, that distinction might matter.
